# How to set all MatrixPlot result with fixed grid size?

Tags: plotting

I have a data:

```
data = {"pieces" -> {"...X,...X,X..X,XXXX,XX.X", ".XX.,XXXX,..X.,..XX,..X.", 
   "...X.,XXXXX,XX..X,....X", ".XXX,.XXX,.XX.,.X..,XX..", 
   "....X,...XX,XXXXX,XXXX.,XXXX.", ".XXX.,XXXXX,XXXX.,..XXX", 
   "XX.,.X.,.XX", "..X.,.XXX,XXXX,X.XX,..X.", ".XXX,XX.X,...X", 
   "XX...,XXXXX,XXXXX,XXXX.,...X.", "...XX,XXXXX,XXXX.,.XXX.,..X..", 
   ".X.X.,.XXX.,XXXXX,XXXXX,..X..", "XX...,.X...,XXX..,.XXXX", 
   "...X,..XX,XXXX,.X..", ".X..,XX..,.XX.,XXXX,XX..", 
   ".X..,XXXX,X.XX,XXX.,XX..", "...XX,XXXXX,..XX.,..XX.", 
   ".X...,XXXX.,XXXXX,.XXXX,...XX", "XXX..,.X...,XXX..,.XXXX,.X..."}, 
 "map" -> {"00222202", "01102001", "02010000", "21022101", "22102001",
    "02102000", "21200210", "22000110", "21102000", "00222200"}, 
 "level" -> 45, "modu" -> "3"}
```

And I define:

```
PiecePlot[piece_] := 
 MatrixPlot[
  ToExpression /@ 
   Characters /@ 
    StringSplit[StringReplace[piece, {"." -> "0", "X" -> "1"}], ","], 
  Mesh -> All, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], FrameTicks -> All]
```

Then evaluate:

```
Show[#, ImageSize -> Tiny] & /@ PiecePlot /@ ("pieces" /. data)
```

And I get:

[image]

But I find the grid size of `3*3` `MatrixPlot` is larger than `5*5` one's. I want something like:

```
         *****
   ***   *****
 { ***,  ***** }
   ***   *****
         *****
```

I mean, every gird with the same size. So how to do it?

Comment: Have you seen `MatrixPlot` documentation for options?

Comment: @Kuba I read it carefully, but I couldn't find a option for controling that.

Comment: Ok, so you want not a grid size but each grid item in every plot to be the same size?

Comment: @Kuba Yes. if `3*3` matrix plot result a 30 pixels * 30 pixels image and I want `5*5` one result 50 pixels * 50 pixels image.

Comment: Well, not really, you probably don't wont "ticks" aread to be scaled with the content.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, but I didn't understand what you said `"ticks" aread to be scaled with the content`... Do you mean it's impossible to scale image size based its content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you specify the size of the padding around the plot explicitly, calculating the right size for the plot is simple:

```
piecePlot[piece_] := Module[{mat, padding = 20, gridSize = 30},
  mat = StringCases[StringSplit[piece, ","], {"X" -> 1, "." -> 0}];
  MatrixPlot[mat, Mesh -> All, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1], FrameTicks -> All,
   ImagePadding -> padding, 
   ImageSize -> (gridSize*Reverse[Dimensions[mat]] + 2*padding)]]
```

Where the only real change from your version are the last two options: `ImagePadding -> padding, ImageSize -> (gridSize*Reverse[Dimensions[mat]] + 2*padding)`. I've simplified the string->matrix conversion a little.

```
piecePlot /@ ("pieces" /. data) // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (still undocumented) form of `ImageSize`, `ImageSize -> a -> b`, to have `a` user units correspond to `b` printer's points.

```
Show[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 15] & /@ PiecePlot /@ ("pieces" /. data) // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Use `ImageSize -> 1 -> {20, 10}` to get

[image]